Task from Brazil ICPC with translating z-array(z-function) to prefix-array(KMP function) and vise-versa
I was working on a task from Brazil ICPC with translating z-array(z-function) to prefix-array(KMP function) and vise-versa.
And there still some failed tests by RTE and one test shows a Wrong Answer so can anyone see where the code breaks and translates wrongly (zFunction and KMP function is just simple KMP and Z-function implementation so i didnt show it in the code)
the full task description:
The first line contains the number t of input data sets 1<= t <= 100000
The first line of each set contains n the length of the  string (2 <= n <=1000000).
The second line of the set contains n - 1 numbers from 0 to n - 1 - function values for all positions of the line from 2 to n in order (if indexing starts from 1).
The sum of string lengths over all input data sets does not exceed 1000000.
For each set of input data, print two lines.
In the first line, print the values of the prefix function for all positions from 2 to n, assuming that the input contained values of the Z function.
In the second line, print the values of the Z function for all positions from 2 to n, assuming that the input included the values of the prefix function.
If any guess cannot be true, print one number -1 on the appropriate line.
If the required function is ambiguous, print any possible set of its values.
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int t = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());

        for (int i = 1; i <= t; i++) {
            ArrayList<Integer> input = new ArrayList<>();
            int n = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine().trim());  //added trim()
            StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder("a");
            StringBuilder prefixLine = new StringBuilder("a");
            int el;
            boolean zFunctionExist = true;
            boolean KMPExist = true;


            String[] inputChar = reader.readLine().trim().split(" "); //added trim()
            for (int j = 2; j <= n; j++) {

                el = Integer.parseInt(inputChar[j - 2].trim());  //added trim()
                input.add(el);

                if (line.length() <= n) {
                    if (line.length() > j - 1) {
                        if (el != 0) {
                            if (j - 1 + el <= line.length() - 1) continue;
                            String sub = line.substring(line.length() - j + 1, el);
                            line.append(sub);
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (el == 0) {
                            line.append((char) (j + 'a' - 1));
                        } else {
                            if (el > line.length()) {
                                String addLine = String.valueOf(line);
                                int count = addLine.length();
                                while (count <= el) {
                                    line.append(addLine);
                                    count *= 2;
                                }
                            } else {
                                line.append(line.substring(0, el));
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }

            ArrayList<Integer> input2 = new ArrayList<>(input);
            input2.add(0, 0);
            for (int ind = 0; ind < input2.size(); ind++) {
                if (input2.get(ind) + ind > input2.size()) zFunctionExist = false;
                if (input2.get(ind) > ind) KMPExist = false;
            }
            if (!zFunctionExist && !KMPExist) {
                answer.append("-1").append("\n");
                answer.append("-1").append("\n");
                break;
            }
            int[] array = zFunction(String.valueOf(line));
            int[] preArray;
            for (int l = 0; l < input.size(); l++) {
                if (array[l] != input.get(l)) {
                    zFunctionExist = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!zFunctionExist) {
                int element = 0;
                for (int k = 2; k <= n; k++) {
                    element = input.get(k - 2);
                    if (element == 0) {
                        prefixLine.append((char) (k + 'a' - 1));
                    } else {
                        prefixLine.append(prefixLine.charAt(element - 1));
                    }
                }
                line = prefixLine;
                array = zFunction(String.valueOf(line));
                preArray = KMP(String.valueOf(line));
                for (int l = 0; l < input.size(); l++) {
                    if (input.get(l) != preArray[l]) {
                        KMPExist = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                preArray = KMP(String.valueOf(line));
                for (int l = 0; l < input.size(); l++) {
                    if (input.get(l) != preArray[l]) {
                        KMPExist = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (zFunctionExist) Arrays.stream(preArray).forEach(e -> answer.append(e).append(" "));
            else answer.append("-1");
            answer.append("\n");
            if (KMPExist) Arrays.stream(array).forEach(e -> answer.append(e).append(" "));
            else answer.append("-1");
            answer.append("\n");

        }

        System.out.println(answer);

    }

I tried find this conterString that break my algorithm but end up with nothing

What's the exact problem specification?

WA stands for wrong answer this problem its only one test from 19

I know what WA stands for; I'm asking if you can post the (full) problem description.
